# Como meto password usando botones, en java netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, botón

De momento puedo meter el password por teclado y que que cada caracter se vea representado con *, pero que tendría que poner en los botones para que me registrara el numero al pulsar los botones? Es una combinación de 4 números el password.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
public class JPasswordFieldTutorial {
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
JPasswordField passwordField = new JPasswordField(20);
JButton button = new JButton("Perform check");
        JButton button1 = new JButton("1");
        JButton button2 = new JButton("2");
        JButton button3 = new JButton("3");
        JButton button4 = new JButton("4");
        JButton button5 = new JButton("5");
        JButton button6 = new JButton("6");
        JButton button7 = new JButton("7");
        JButton button8 = new JButton("8");
        JButton button9 = new JButton("9");
public JPasswordFieldTutorial() {
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
char [] input = passwordField.getPassword();
if(checkIfCorrect(input)) {
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Password is correct!");
} else {
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Password is incorrect!");
}
}
});
```

El password lo chequeo aqui.

```
private boolean checkIfCorrect(char [] input) {
boolean isCorrect = false;
char [] correctPass = {'1','2','3','4'};

if(input.length != correctPass.length) {
isCorrect = false;
} else {
isCorrect = Arrays.equals(input, correctPass);
}
Arrays.fill(correctPass,'0');
return isCorrect;
}
```

Comment: No entendí bien, necesitas saber cuál es el número de boton que presiono el usuario ? Si es así debería obtener la propiedad text de los jbutton mediante gettext()

Comment: si que el password se meta presionando los buttons y no por teclado, como tendría que ponerlo?